# Slick, hide items on the sides

Tags: html, css, slick.js

I would like the sliders on the sides are not visible. Only 2 items in the middle, then 1 item on mobile.

Here is a diagram: http://nsa37.casimages.com/img/2017/07/17/170717011620615002.jpg and my codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/owOJpa

The red slides must not be visible.

The simplest solution would be to group 2 citations into a single item, but the problem would be on mobile. There would be 2 items on mobile too, which I do not want.

```
$('.customers-review__list').slick({
 arrows: false,
 dots: true,
   mobileFirst: true,
   responsive: [
    {
     breakpoint: 1,
     settings: {
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
     }
   },

   {
    breakpoint: 768,
    settings: {
     slidesToShow: 2,
     slidesToScroll: 2,
    }
   },
 ]
});
```

Do you have any idea how to get there? Thanks.

Comment: what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: I wish to have only 2 visible elements in the middle rather than 4.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `max-width` property on `.customers-review__item`, if possible. That should get your work done.

Comment: The slides must have 700px maximum, I can't remove it.

Comment: but however widths are calculated by the slick.js